# Jsp to gather information from Multiple Databases

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a few databases that I need to connect to the Servlet;(YES these DB are fake, for a school project)

First I need to grab the Student DB :

To get to the StudentSchedule 

 To get to the Sections:

 To finally obtain the classes names the students are taking http://puu.sh/cO7gN/9d303ebe8b.png

I currently created a Servlet to gather this information:

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ScheduleServlet"})
    public class ScheduleServlet extends HttpServlet {


        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */

              int iD = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iD"));
               int cRN = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cRN"));
               String courseID = request.getParameter("courseID");
               String courseName = request.getParameter("courseName");
               System.out.println(iD); 

                Student s1=new Student();
                s1.findDB(iD);

                StudentSchedule s2 = new StudentSchedule();
                s2.findDB(cRN);


                Section s3 = new Section();
                s3.findDB(cRN);


                Course s4 = new Course();
                s4.findDB(courseID);
                 s4.findDB(courseName);

                String cn=s4.getCourseName();
                System.out.println(cn);
                RequestDispatcher rd;

                HttpSession ses1=request.getSession();
                ses1.setAttribute("s4", s4);


                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ScheduleView.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request,response);



            }
        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */

        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

I also have a Webpage that pulls up their information: http://puu.sh/cO7p0/5f64c27869.jpg

 But once I click on the View Schedule button no information about "Larry's" Classes are revealed.

## How can I obtain the information that I need to solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

and code is:

```
 <%@page import="Business.Student"%>
    <%@page import="Business.StudentSchedule"%>
    <%@page import="Business.Section"%>
    <%@page import="Business.Course"%>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Schedule View</title>
        </head>
        <body>

             <%
                HttpSession ses1=request.getSession();
                Course s4= (Course)ses1.getAttribute("s4");


                %> 

                <h4>Here is your Information</h4>
            <table border="1" width="75%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="10">Student Info</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                         <%--TABLE LABLES OF ACCOUNT INFORMATION  --%>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                        <td colspan="2">Course Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <%--TABLE DISPLAY OF ACCOUNT INFORMATION  --%>
                        <td colspan="2">Classes: </td>
                        <td colspan="2"><%= s4.getCourseName()%></td>
                        </tr>



                </tbody>
            </table>
                    <table width="50%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2">


            </table>  
        </body>
    </html>
```

NOTE: I can connect to the Databases, I just need to find a way to get the servlet to work to get the students Schedule viewed up on the database, all the Business Objects are working, since I've tested them, its putting the work to the jsp page from gathering all the database to get the information, that's the problem, getting the JSP page to go through all the databases to get the actual students classes.
I can connect to the databases, I just want to see how to use the servlet to connect all to get the information I need to find that classes.

Comment: Student Schedule: http://jsfiddle.net/8ym5w2ym/

Comment: Student: http://jsfiddle.net/8uw7ff7e/

Comment: Section: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpkktew3/

Comment: Course: http://jsfiddle.net/z8vo9v7k/

Comment: All of these are The business objects that I am using for this, I have to use all of them to get the classes for the student